# How to make optional required for differents attributes on differents inherited classes on EF6 , (businnes required rules)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

How to make optional REQUIRED for the same attribute on different inherited classes on EF6.

Why the 'required attribute' from one child is required for other child? 
Why does entity framework merge all data anotations to base classe 'Person' if the base class is non required attributes?

I've used the same classes on MVC to create required fields on cshtml, and it works. The MVC understands only required field from one child and not make any 'wrong merge' with those two child classes.

For example:

```
//EF Codefirst Class
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int key{get;set;}
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string email{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string phone{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string address{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string manager{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string Discriminator{ get; set; }
}
//My Inherited classes
public class Employee : Person
{
    [Required]
    public override string name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string phone{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string manager{ get; set; }
} 
public class Manager: Person
{
    [Required]
    public override string name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string email{ get; set; }
}
//And my sample function 'Add PersonManager' 
 private void  InsertPerson()
 {
    using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var m = new Manager() ;
            m.name = "my name" ;
            m.email = "my@email.com";
            m.address =" something";

            ctx.Person.Add(m);        

            ctx.SaveChanges();  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         // Why, if I try to Add my Person 'Manager', the attribute : phone and manager is REQUIRED?
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to do doesn't make sense.  the `[Required]` attribute will mark the field as not null in the DB, which means other classes that share that table will also automatically be "required".  The database isn't going to support the idea of a conditional null requirement.

Comment: @Claies, in the database all fields in the example is varchar(500) null.  It will support,  the database is already created.

Comment: It doesn't make sense in the way that EF works;  I was not suggesting that your business model is flawed, but you cannot set EF up this way.  If you don't want feedback on your posted code, I'm not sure how else to help.

Comment: Cleies, it needs to exist one way to make it work on EF, because on MVC the inheritance works as we see on code. The required fields on Employee dont merge to the Manager. They are independent. They just recieve the things from base class.

Comment: No, as the answer provided explains, EF does not treat inheritance the same way C# itself does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are using TPH strategy. All entities will be merged in one table, EF handles what must be null or not null.

If you use TPT strategy, EF will create different tables for each entity. To learn more about inheritance strategies take a look at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx

To use TPT instead of TPH, you must define a "key" in your child class, like this:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int employeeId;
    [Required]
    public override string name;
    [Required]
    public override string phone;
    [Required]
    public override string manager;
}
```

Another way to do this is using Fluent API. Like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>() 
    .HasKey(c => c.key); 

modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
   .ToTable("Employees");

modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
   .ToTable("Managers");
```

To see more about this, take a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.5